# Wordpress different image sizes based on template part

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-images

The folder structure in my theme looks like this:

- wp-content/themes/theme/

  - partials/

    - content-hero.php

I am using `get_template_part('partials/content, 'hero')` to include the template part.

I am using the `wp_calculate_image_sizes` filter in `functions.php` to add custom sizes property to my images. I need to change the size depending on what template part is calling the `wp_get_attachment_image` function but I am not sure how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the size before the get_template_part into a variable, like:

```
$thesize = "here go the size you need";
set_query_var( 'variable_size', $thesize );
get_template_part('partials/content, 'hero');
```

So now inside content-hero.php you will have available the variable $variable_size with what you need.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: This seems to be a bit of hack but its working as described.